# How can I trigger onResume in idleTimeout jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make a modification to the functionality of Eric Hynds's [jQuery IdleTimeout plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/a-new-and-improved-jquery-idle-timeout-plugin/) and not having much luck.  When 'onTimeout' is called, I'm trying to trigger the 'onResume' function to start the timer again and then close the dialog window.  When it's working, you should see the dialog window upon idle, and then disappear and then reappear after the same idle time - in a loop.  Why a loop? I'm going to be adding more to the 'onTimeout' call once I get this part working.

Here's my code, I know from firebug that my issue is with how I trigger the onResume call (line 9). The plugin binds the 'onResume' call to the click event via the dialog window, but obviously there won't be a user click in this instance.

```
$.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    idleAfter: 5,
    warningLength: 5,
    pollingInterval: 2,
    keepAliveURL: 'keepalive.php',
    serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
    onTimeout: function(){
        $(this).dialog('close');
        self.onResume();
    },
    onIdle: function(){
        $(this).dialog("open");
    },
    onCountdown: function(counter){
        $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
    }
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The plugin binds the 'onResume' call to the click event via the dialog
>   window, but obviously there won't be a user click in this instance.

This is not quite true. The plugin binds the "Resume" link to an internal function that actually pings the server, *then* calls whatever onResume callback you've defined. You're trying to call onResume() directly -- which is OK, but it's not going to actually resume your session.

You might be better off mimicking a click on the Resume link directly, like so:

```
 onTimeout: function() {
   $(this).dialog('close');
   $(this).data('idletimeout').resume.trigger('click');
 },
```

Comment: Elliot, thanks for responding and for explaining how the onResume works - now it makes more sense!  I tried your suggested code and firebug still has an error:

      "$(this).data("ontimeout") is undefined"   


Finally, I'm ok if 'onResume' doesn't resume my session, I've got that taken care of, I just want the idle timer to restart.

Comment: Hmm, I think that might actually be due to a flaw in the plugin... Does your dialog close call work? The brute force way would be to call _$('div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').trigger('click')_.

Comment: Actually, it's a flaw in _my_ code, since for some reason I was calling it "ontimeout" - change it to _data('idletimeout')_ and it should work for you. I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: Elliot - that did the trick, thank you! 

I did notice that after the dialog closed, it still look the slightest mouse movement to restart the idle countdown, although I fixed that in the jquery.idletimer.js file by adding the JS event 'click' to the list of events (line #90). 

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

"The plugin binds the 'onResume' call to the click event via the dialog window, but obviously there won't be a user click in this instance."

An option -

The click event can be programmatically triggered using the trigger jquery api. e.g.

```
$(this).trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/